# Changing value of current value in vbScript in InforVisual ERP System

Tags: vbscript, erp

I am trying to create a macro to speed up an ERP system process in Infor Visual.
I am essentially trying to go from the inventory transaction entry window to the issue and return by exception window and enter the right values for each textbox so the system brings up the right inventory transaction and goes through the process of issuing. I am able to get through the issue and return section, but I am not at all sure how to alter the value of the currently selected box.
The code looks like this:

```
set shl = createobject("wscript.shell")
'Dim WshShell
'Set WshShell = CreateObject("Forms.TextBox.1")
shl.sendkeys "%{e}"
shl.sendkeys "{x}"
shl.sendkeys "{TAB}"
shl.sendkeys "{TAB}"

'WshShell = (WORKORDER_BASE_ID)


'ISSUE_RTN
'ISSUE

'Dim value As String

'vbActive = "5"

'WORKORDER_BASE_ID

'document.write(WORKORDER_BASE_ID)

'set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
'WScript.Echo (objShell.CurrentDirectory)

'objShell.CurrentDirectory = WORKORDER_BASE_ID
'shl.sendkeys "{TAB}"

'vbCurrent = WORKORDER_LOT_ID
'shl.sendkeys "{TAB}"

'vbCurrent = WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID
'shl.sendkeys "{TAB}"

'vbCurrent = WORKORDER_SUB_ID
```

The ' indicate commented out sections that were previous attempts to make what I want to happen happen. The set.schl with the schl.sendkeys is what's able to access the keyboard and go to the tab I want to enter the values in. The two TAB lines go to the first line I want to change. And the value of that first cell would be the field value "WORKORDER_BASE_ID"

That's the context of the problem, but for the most part I would really just like to know how to alter the current cell that the program is in, thanks.

P.S. Infor Visuals doesn't do macros like other programs where it records what you do, so you just have to tell it what to do with VBScript.

I'm no expert with VBScript, so all I was expecting with all of that commented out code was to in some way alter the current cell to the field I described.

Comment: In general, sendkeys scripts are unreliable, but what key would you normally press to alter the current cell? In Excel, for example, it would be F2.

Comment: Well pressing TAB or just clicking on a cell brings you to that cell, then you would just type the value you want. Also I'm not sure if these are classified as cells, maybe field is a better word for it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I just used more of that command, didn't know it could take variables

```
set shl = createobject("wscript.shell")
shl.sendkeys "%{e}"
shl.sendkeys "{x}"
shl.sendkeys "{TAB}"
shl.sendkeys "{TAB}"
shl.sendkeys(WORKORDER_BASE_ID)
shl.sendkeys "{TAB}"
shl.sendkeys(WORKORDER_LOT_ID)
shl.sendkeys "{TAB}"
shl.sendkeys(WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID)
shl.sendkeys "{TAB}"
shl.sendkeys(WORKORDER_SUB_ID)
shl.sendkeys "{TAB}"
```

I imagine there's still a more eloquent or general solution that exists, but this has worked for me.